# Html <p> tag expand dynamically to parent that is next to another div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

How could to put the right box next to the left box (inline-block) with precise sizes? I can put it up, but the size will not be the same in different browsers. Then how could I put the left box near to the right box without that whitespace? Thank you.

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.entry {
    width: 560px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
    position: relative; 
}
.entry .img-cont,.body-cont {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.entry .img-cont {
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.entry .body-cont {
    width: 508px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.entry .body-cont p {
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
    <div class="img-cont">
        <img src="http://bit.ly/1RabLNk"/>
    </div>
    <div class="body-cont">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi nulla libero, sollicitudin a erat semper, gravida pharetra augue. Phasellus convallis ultrices dolor vitae imperdiet. Curabitur mollis odio neque, in dictum nisi finibus nec. Vivamus pulvinar, turpis a volutpat semper, lacus diam convallis.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

see this
   http://jsfiddle.net/leandroparrar/6omjqefj

Here is an example of what the problem looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is pretty close to what you need.

If you zero-our the margins on the `p` element in `.body-cont`, that will get rid of the extra whitespace that appears on top of the paragraph.

If you try to use `inline-block`'s, it is easy to get some extra whitespace between elements due to carriage-returns (newlines) in the HTML file.

If you use `display: table-cell` on `.img-cont` and `.body-cont`, then the
two elements will rest side-by-side and you can control the horizontal spacing using left/right padding as needed.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.entry {
  width: 560px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table;
}
.entry .img-cont, .entry .body-cont {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.entry .img-cont img {
  display: block;
}
.entry .body-cont p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
  <div class="img-cont">
    <img src="http://bit.ly/1RabLNk" />
  </div>
  <div class="body-cont">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi nulla libero, sollicitudin a erat semper, gravida pharetra augue. Phasellus convallis ultrices dolor vitae imperdiet. Curabitur mollis odio neque, in dictum nisi finibus nec. Vivamus pulvinar,
      turpis a volutpat semper, lacus diam convallis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But what I need is to remove the white-space between the left div and the right div. Is there any margin, padding or display propertie that I'm missing? Thank you!

Comment: I made some minor adjustments based on your comments.